# Blender install on an old computer (Athlon 700mhz AMD)

Tags: installation

I am interested in putting into use an old computer I got sitting around the garage: Athlon 700Mhz AMD computer with 16 Mb rab.
The OS I´d like to use is Xubuntu. 
I got a 2014 Nvidia Graphics card lying around as well. 
What steps do I need to do to configure the Nvidia drivers on Xubuntu?
I´m familiar with the terminal + some geeky terms to repos.
But I´ll be very thankful if you could help me in the right steps. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender

Comment: It is possible that you can use blender on such machine, but don't expect much. I doubt that you modern versions of blender would give you any joy on a machine from the previous century.... However, advice to configure linux or install drivers is not something that belongs in this site.